# Gradle project sync failed android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded Arc library form github and imported it as module then I got this error.

Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-4' in: C:\Users\shahek\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
Open Android SDK Manager
I also installed Api 15.

This is my build.gradle setting.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.shahek.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: Install API Level 4 too (Android 1.6)

Comment: In android SDK minimum is API 8. how can i install API Level 4 ?

Comment: Soo. maybe you can link the library here ? Maybe you can change the library config to use minSdk 8. Btw you can install the API level 4 too if you check the "Obsolete" checkbox in the standalone sdk manager

Comment: Problem Solved: I have installed API Level 4 and some other components Android Studio asked for.  You rock man !  But I got a question that how did you know I should install API level 4 ???

Comment: It's easy. " failed to find target" "android-4"  means API level 4. Ex "android-19" means API level 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install version 23 and all this things must be solved.
If it don't help you,
try to download this library from github and add into project and modify min sdk version in gradle/manifest to yours 18.

Good luck.